# Compare and list columns data of 2 tables where there is data change. (Something like minus, but need to list only columns with changed data)

Tags: sql, oracle, compare

I have many tables and its back up tables. Each table has 250+ columns. Now I want to compare each table with it's back up table and list the rows which have got changed. And need to display data only column of changed data. If a particular column isn't changed then that data will be displayed as null.

Example.

Table_X

```
---------------------------------------------------
|EmployeeID  |Name    |Age    |...|Address        |
---------------------------------------------------
|EMP001      |Raju    |35     |...|Bangalore      |
|EMP002      |Gopal   |40     |...|Chennai        |
---------------------------------------------------
```

Table_X_Backup

```
---------------------------------------------------
|EmployeeID  |Name    |Age    |...|Address        |
---------------------------------------------------
|EMP001      |Raju    |35     |...|Bangalore      |
|EMP002      |Gopal   |40     |...|Hyderabad      |
---------------------------------------------------
```

I want resulting change-set table as below.

Change_Set_Table_X

```
-----------------------------------------------
|EmployeeID  |ChangedColumns                  |
-----------------------------------------------
|EMP002      |Address <Other Columns if Any>  |
-----------------------------------------------
```

OR

Delta_Table_X

```
---------------------------------------------------
|EmployeeID  |Name    |Age    |...|Address        |
---------------------------------------------------
|EMP001      |NULL    |NULL   |...|NULL           |
|EMP002      |NULL    |NULL   |...|CHANGED        |
---------------------------------------------------
```

**Note**:

- Using Oracle DB
- Columns are heterogeneous data types (comprising of varchar2, number and clob)
- There are more than 250+ columns in each table. So can't compare column to column manually. I have found a function which lists all the columns of table it might help.

  *SELECT column_name
  FROM user_tab_cols
  WHERE table_name = 'Table_X';*

  *SELECT LISTAGG(column_name, ', ') within group (order by column_name) FROM user_tab_cols where table_name = 'Table_X' and column_name not in (Columns Of Clob Data Type)  group by table_name;*

Code that I've tried. Please suggest improvisation of efficient code.

```
Insert into Delta_Table_X
With
A as (Select EmployeeID, Name, Age, ..., Address from Table_X MINUS Select EmployeeID, Name, Age, ..., Address from Table_X_Backup),
B as (Select EmployeeID, Name, Age, ..., Address from Table_X_Backup MINUS Select EmployeeID, Name, Age, ..., Address from Table_X)
Select 
A.EmployeeID "EmployeeID",
Case when nvl(A.Name, 'NULL') <> nvl(B.Name, 'NULL') then null else 'CHANGED' end "Name",
Case when nvl(A...., 'NULL') <> nvl(B...., 'NULL') then null else 'CHANGED' end "...",
Case when nvl(A.Address, 'NULL') <> nvl(B.Address, 'NULL') then null else 'CHANGED' end "Address"
FROM
A join B
on A.EmployeeID = B.EmployeeID
/
```

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: This looks like "give me a code" question. What's your attempt so far?

Comment: show us what have you tried

Comment: Is there a primary/unique key on the table?

Comment: @KaushikNayak, Of course I'm looking at an efficient code. It would be a great help if you know the way of solving it efficiently!

Comment: @nikhilsugandh, Currently I've tried brute set operation + brute force technique.

With A as (select <all non clob params> from Table_X MINUS select <all non clob params> from Table_X_Backup), B as (select <all non clob params> from Table_X_Backup MINUS select <all non clob params> from Table_X)
Select case when nvl(A.EmployeeID, 'NULL') <> nvl(B.EmployeeID,'NULL') then null else 'CHANGED' end "EmployeeID",
--- <Similarly for all columns> ---
from A join B
on A.EmployeeID = B.EmployeeID;

Comment: @Boneist, there is no constraint defined. But EmployeeID can be taken as unique.

Comment: @All, my apologies for not mentioning the code I've tried. I assumed explanation will be enough.

Comment: @MohanNV if there's no constraint, shouldn't there be? Otherwise, what happens if there are two rows for an employee id in one or both of the tables? How would you know which row matches to which?

Comment: @Boneist, even if there are 2 employees at both the tables, then minus operator will remove it before join operator. By, the way - as I told, you can take it as primary key so the 2 same EmployeeID won't exist in same table.